# Use max function to find longest string in list of lists

Tags: python, max

I can do this with List Comprehension, no problem, but how can it work just using max()?

```
# This works
a_list = ["a_string", "the_longest_string", "string"]
longest_string = max(a_list, key=len)
print(longest_string)
# Now how to do it when the data structure is a list of lists
a_list = [["a_string"], ["the_longest_string"], ["string"]]
longest_string = max(a_list, key=len)
print(longest_string)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you expect out of that list of lists? The list with the longest string? Or just the longest string itself? Will there always only be one string in those inner lists?

Comment: In the second case, all len are 1, so max return the one he wants

Comment: `map(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a_list), key=len)`…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
max(a_list, key=lambda x: len(*x))
```

Comment: What does the * do?

Comment: @nicomp try to `print(["a","b"])` and `print(*["a","b"])` and you'll see the difference